# Why Ammonium bifluoride is used in the iodometric estimation of copper in brass?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

When brass solution (mixed with nitric acid and urea) is to be estimated for amount of copper present, ammonia is added to neutralize the solution. This gives a turbidity which can be dissolve by adding ammonium bifluoride (NH4HF2).
What exactly causes the turbidity? Which compound formation is responsible for the turbid appearance?

Comment: The turbidity is possibly traces of iron, ferric hydroxide, and possibly aluminum that was in the brass. Fluoride complexes with both.  Ferric ion interferes with the iodine titration method, lowering its activity reduces the interference. The word estimation is bothersome; this method should be reasonably quantitative, what shortcuts are being taken?